# Defining methods in super class for sub classes

Tags: java

How would one go about defining a method in a super class but leave the implementation to the sub classes?

Comment: Make it abstract? Or did I miss something? Or is this part of some homework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the [method `abstract`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void doStuff();
}

class B extends A {
    void doStuff() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Note that...

> If a class includes abstract methods, the class itself must be declared `abstract`

Abstract classes can't be constructed (so `new A()` would be an error, but `new B()` would be fine), and subclasses need to implement all abstract methods unless they're also abstract.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void doStuff();
}

abstract class B extends A {
    // This is fine since B is abstract
}

class C extends A {
    // This is an error since doStuff() isn't implemented
}
```

With an abstract class, you can mix abstract and normal methods:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void doStuff();

    void doOtherStuff() {
        // Subclasses don't need to implement this
    }
}
```

If all of the methods are abstract, it may make more sense to use an [`interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29), since classes an implement multiple interfaces:

```
interface DoesStuff {
    void doStuff();
}

interface DoesOtherStuff {
    void doOtherStuff();
}

class B implements DoesStuff, DoesOtherStuff {
    void doStuff() {
        // stuff
    }

    void doOtherStuff() {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Note: Methods in an interface are automatically `abstract` and `public`, unlike methods in classes, which are by default [package private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and not abstract.

Answer (score 4):

Make super class as `abstract` class and define method as `abstract` method which forces subclasses to provide implementations (or) make themselves as `abstract`.

Example:

```
abstract class Super {
    abstract void absMethod();
}

class Sub extends Super {
    void absMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Super class in example must by itself also be `abstract`.

Answer (score 1):

You would create an abstract method in the super class.

```
abstract class SuperClass {
   public abstract void mustImplement();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
   public void mustImplement() {
       // Do stuff here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should declared abstract. e.g.

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  protected abstract void myMethod();
}


class MyChildClass extends MyBaseClass
{
  protected void myMethod()
  {
    // here is my implementation!
  }
}
```

Comment: Super class must by itself also be `abstract` in order to hold `abstract` methods.